# In the SR latch, with Q=1 and Q'=0 (ie.S=1,R=0),why do we assume Q remains same when S changes to 0?Details

Tags: latch

In the following video on SR latch (from University of Illinois) on youtube
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUfZladDqq8
,

(The point illustrated in this composite screenshot!)

[image: screenshot]

The "instructor" says the following 1mn 10 seconds into the main video --"Let's change S to 0(from 1),then with S and R as 0, both Q and Q' will hold their values"--Well that's what I don't get!!Now please try to see through the following clumsy description of my doubt and clear my confusion (I am a computer science student and this course is new for me,so please bear with me) :

How will Q and Q' hold their values?I mean, we are assuming that Q,which is fed as input to the bottom NOR gate,DOESN'T CHANGE IF S IS CHANGED FROM 1 TO 0!!!I completely don't get it.Isn't Q dependent on(is a function of) S and should change the moment S changes?I mean,S determines the value of Q'(For example S has to be 1 for Q' to be 0),and Q' in turn determines the value of Q.So, doesn't it mean it depends on S? Shouldn't Q change the moment S changes? You see, as per what I have studied so far, if there is a single logic gate, then we expect the output to be dependent on the inputs, and we expect it to change the moment any input changes, ISN'T IT?We don't expect the output to stay the same (or hold its value) if the inputs that determine it change.Then how come in the SR latch we expect the output Q of the upper NOR gate to hold its value when S changes from 1 to 0? Isn't it ironic that we automatically assume Q to remain the same(preserve its value) while the whole point of designing the SR latch is to preserve a value? Let me explain further.

Say in our circuit we use a voltage range of 0-2V to refer to 0(low) and a voltage range of 3-5V to refer to 1(high).So when we expect Q to be logical 1 or 3-5 Volts even after the input S that determines it changes, do we expect "SOMETHING" to hold that 3-5 volts of Q?What holds it?Is there somekind of ELECTRICAL REMNANCE,LATENCY or STORAGE involved?Or S changes much faster than Q could change!I am so utterly confused.I could just remember the whole thing by rote without understanding it, but I don't want to do that.So please answer what's up.I am sure you got what I mean to ask.The bottomline being---"S determines Q' which in turn determines Q, so when S changes, I expect Q to change or to be in an undefined state as the input indirectly determining it has changed.I just don't get why the instructor IMPLICITLY ASSUMES Q WILL STILL BE 1 when S changes to 0.

Comment: Why the shouting?

Comment: First time and first question on this forum, so please bear with me this time.Once I learn how to highlight some lines, I will stick to the etiquette instead of using Caps.I apologize.

Comment: That's okay, but please edit your question to make it reasonable readable. Here is some markup help: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @CamilStaps In the Maths section of stackexchange, the seasoned contributors edit the question.So I have no idea about markup as I never had to use it in maths section.I hope you understand my problem at the moment.

Comment: There is no problem if you just take some time to read a little on the editing help and to edit your question. _'Seasoned contributors' aren't there to layout your question_.

Comment: @CamilStaps I will surely learn the markup.But please answer my question as I just can't move ahead in my book without it.I will learn Latex for sure.

Comment: You don't have to learn LaTeX for this question, just remove the shouting so that it is nice to read. This will be my last comment in this discussion, I've made my point.

Comment: @CamilStaps Generally SE sites teach by example, dont fight back and forth in comments, just edit and improve it and the user will know after that point.

Comment: @Kortuk okay, sorry for this then. It will not happen again.

Comment: @CamilStaps I appreciate you giving advice, but lets try to be friendly, often someone stuck on a problem is not going to want to address learning the site that moment. They will take some time and minor edits by you will both earn you a badge and make their first experience more hospitable.

Comment: @TSingh Now you are here to get help from experts, please put some time into your question and when users try to help teach you how to use the site please listen and take constructive advice.

Comment: I can excuse some usage of caps. The real problem here is extreme verbosity and generally a lack of focus. I tried salvaging the question, but halfway through I couldn't remember what point the question was trying to make.

Comment: @Kortuk - `just edit and improve it and the user will know after that point.` I generally agree this is the case. However, in this situation, the OP has actually said `In the Maths section of stackexchange, the seasoned contributors edit the question.So I have no idea about markup as I never had to use it in maths section`, so it seems that you can't always assume the OP will bother to look at and understand the changes others make to his posts.

Answer (score 6):

The point you're missing is the fact that once the Q output has gone high, the output of the gate that S is connected to is forced low, **regardless** of whether S remains high or subesquently goes low. In other words, once that happens, the output of that gate is *no longer* dependent on the value of S.

By symmetry, the same can be said of the R input. Once it goes high, the Q output is forced low, and as long as S is also low, the Q' output goes high. At that point, the value of R no longer matters, and it can go high or low without affecting the state of the latch.

Comment: I don't know why caps are assumed to be shouting, but every netiquette guide I've ever seen mentions it: [a](http://www.lemondrop.com/2009/09/02/woman-fired-over-caps-netiquette/), [b](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1855), [c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_(technology)#Netiquette), [d](http://www.networketiquette.net/do_not_use_all_caps.htm), [e](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/08/14/how-to-be-polite-while-youre-online-practicing-good-netiquette/), [f](http://thewiseinternet.blogspot.com/2013/01/netiquette-rule-2-no-all-caps.html), etc.

Comment: Out hours back to the days when the only don't you had was decided for you by what model VT terminal you were using and all-caps was the only way to add emphasis. But some users still had habits from the time when lower case letters were considered an unnecessary luxury, so continued to write all-caps.

Comment: s/don't/ font ...